# How to combine a png and a path in inkscape

Tags: gimp, inkscape, png, path, raster

I made an image on Gimp to use as a background for my icon made in inkscape.

The general shape of the icon is a rectangle path with round corner.

I imported the png in inkscape, and I want to combine (difference I think) the imported png and the rectangle path: so my icon will remain rectangle with the png background.

I don't if it possible, and if it is, how to do it?

If you have another idea on how to it, feel free to suggest.

Thanks a lot

Comment: you might want to look into / google for using 'clipping masks' in Inkscape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you need is to clip your image (clipping is using a path to cut and define the shape of another path or image).

In order to do this select both the object and the clipping path.

The clipping path must be above the object to be clipped in z-order.

Then use the Object → Clip → Set command.

To unclip a clipped object, select the object and use the Object → Clip → Release command.

The clipping path is then restored as a regular object, placed just above the formerly clipped object in z-order.